# Android app using xamarin supports Jquery?

Tags: android, jquery, xamarin

Am new to Android application development, We are in process of exploring it.
I have a question does Android app supports Jquery ??
We are using Xamarin tool for app development

Comment: Xamarin uses a C# stack that compiles into a native Android application, with no JavaScript in the picture, so it isn't clear what your question means. Consider using PhoneGap if a JS environment is comfortable for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) integrates well with Android.

Here are some good resources for you:

http://jquerymobile.com/resources/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery-mobile-forms/

Comment: Do we have link where we can achieve the same in Xamarin, As I don't know where I can add the reference for Jquery